# How to insert one million notification records for one million user records in MongoDB efficiently using the best practices?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have two collections Users and Notifications.
I have 1 million users and I want to create a notification record for each user so I need to insert 1 million notification records. What is the best practice to do so efficiently using MongoDB and nodejs? should I iterate over users manually or are there built-in utilities in MongoDB to do so efficiently.

`Users` schema:

```json
  {
    "_id": "61b76dcef2d79f189f619daa",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "name": "test"
  }
```

`Notifications` schema:

```json
  {
    "_id": "61b76dcef2d79f189f610000",
    "userID": "61b76dcef2d79f189f619daa", //this is ref to user
    "data": "test data",
    "isSeen": false
  }
```

Comment: If your source data is JSON, CSV, or TSV formatted, then [`mongoimport`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/) should work very well for you.

Comment: I have no source data. I generate notification records for each user programmatically on server

Comment: What do your `users` docs look like?  What do you want the `notifications` docs to look like?

Comment: user schema:
{   "_id" :"61b76dcef2d79f189f619daa",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "name": "test"
}



          , notification schema:
{   "_id" :"61b76dcef2d79f189f610000",
    "userID": "61b76dcef2d79f189f619daa",  //this is ref to user
    "data": "test data",
    "isSeen": false
}

Comment: So, you already have the `Users` collection and you want to create the `Notifications` collection from the `Users` collection?  Given a `Users` doc, how exactly do you want to create a `Notifications` doc?  Do you have some notifications to insert for each user? ... or is there a "base"/"minimal" notification doc you want to create for each user?  Currently I'm wondering if a `Users` aggregation pipeline could create each doc for the `Notifications` collection and the last stage of the pipeline would be `"$out"`.

Comment: Yes, I have the same notification for each user. It's a broadcast notification (general announcement)

Comment: Thank you rickhg12hs  it works.
I just made a tiny change by replacing $out with $merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to create a `notifications` collection with some "seed" data.

[MongoDB Atlas "Export Pipeline to Node"]

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

/*
 * Requires the MongoDB Node.js Driver
 * https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native
 */

const agg = [
  {
    '$project': {
      'userId': '$_id', 
      'data': 'test data', 
      'isSeen': {
        '$not': true
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$out': 'notifications'
  }
];

MongoClient.connect(
  'connection string',
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
  function(connectErr, client) {
    assert.equal(null, connectErr);
    const coll = client.db('yourDatabase').collection('users');
    coll.aggregate(agg, (cmdErr, result) => {
      assert.equal(null, cmdErr);
    });
    client.close();
  });
```

Comment: Thank you rickhg12hs it works. I just made a tiny change by replacing $out with $merge –